# How to make real-time search bar - React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

There are 2 arrays. One holds all the initial objects. The other is to store the selected objects from the first array. I need to search through the first array and select the matching objects and put only the matching objects into second array depending on the ID value from a text input.

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([
    {id:'OR0001', name:'bob', mobile:'0779632589'},
    {id:'OR0026', name:'mike', mobile:'0785412365'},
    {id:'OR0024', name:'sandy', mobile:'0758463987'},
    {id:'OR0012', name:'kenedy', mobile:'0763215695'},
    {id:'OR0006', name:'brown', mobile:'0712546325'},
    {id:'OR0023', name:'luke', mobile:'0778965236'},
    {id:'OR0041', name:'anne', mobile:'0745874563'}
]);

const [selectedOrders, setSelectedOrders] = useState([]);
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
```

The Following is what I tried

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setSelectedOrders([]);
    if(searchInput){            
        var reg = new RegExp(searchInput+"+", "i");
        for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++){
            var order = orders[i];
            if(reg.test(order.orderId)){                    
                setSelectedOrders([...selectedOrders, order]);
            }
        }
    }
}, [searchInput])
```

But this doesn't work. Only the last match is inserted into the 2nd array. Also when keeping on typing the same object is repeatedly added into the array. The 2nd array is only emptied if I enter a mismatch in the text input.

Example: Something like the following is happenning

```
''       => show all
'O'      => [OR0041]
'OR'     => [OR0041, OR0041]
'OR0'    => [OR0041, OR0041, OR0041]
'OR00'   => [OR0041, OR0041, OR0041, OR0041]
'OR002'  => [OR0041, OR0041, OR0041, OR0041, OR0023]
'OR0024' => [OR0041, OR0041, OR0041, OR0041, OR0023, OR0024]
'OR002'  => [OR0041, OR0041, OR0041, OR0041, OR0023, OR0024, OR0023]
'OR00'   => [OR0041, OR0041, OR0041, OR0041, OR0023, OR0024, OR0023, OR0041]
'OR00s'  => []
'OR00'   => [OR0041]
'OR0'    => [OR0041, OR0041]
'OR'     => [OR0041, OR0041, OR0041]
'O'      => [OR0041, OR0041, OR0041, OR0041]
''       => show all
```

What I expect from the above is like this

```
''       => show all
'O'      => show all
'OR'     => show all
'OR0'    => show all
'OR00'   => show all
'OR002'  => [OR0026, OR0024, OR0023]
'OR0024' => [OR0024]
'OR002'  => [OR0026, OR0024, OR0023]
'OR00'   => show all
'OR00s'  => []
'OR00'   => show all
'OR0'    => show all
'OR'     => show all
'O'      => show all
''       => show all
```

I have separately implemented show all if text input is empty

```
function chooseDisplayArray(){
    if(!searchInput){
        return orders;
    }else{
        return selectedOrders;
    }
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong in the useEffect? Or is there a better way to get what I want?

EDIT: Problem recreated in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-ganguly-cvdpp7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked out. I still don't know the reason that this didn't work. But I found a work around.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setSelectedOrders([]);
  if(searchInput){            
      var reg = new RegExp(searchInput+"+", "i");
      var arr = [];                          //<----introduce a new empty array
      for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++){
          var order = orders[i];
          if(reg.test(order.orderId)){                    
              //setSelectedOrders([...selectedOrders, order]);
              arr.push(order);               //<----add object into new array using push() method
          }
      }
      setSelectedOrders(arr);                //<-----set the newly created array into the state
  }
}, [searchInput])
```

Although this works great, I think using raw variables without states is wrong/ bad writing in React??

So if anyone can explain what I did wrong in the first attempt, or tell me how to use states for the new one, help is greatly welcomed.